# How to fix opening profile correctly

Tags: google-chrome

So when I open Chrome, I see a box

[image: box]

And my bookmark icons are gone. Anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1. Click on the menu icon on the top right corner of your chrome browser
2. On the drop down menu, click the signed in as ______
3. Under users section, click the delete this user button and takes him
   off away.
4. Restart Google chrome and add the user and Chrome will be in a good
   shape.

Or else try this:

[**Fix Google Chrome “Your Profile Could Not be Opened Correctly”**](https://merchantprotocol.com/573/google-chrome-your-profile-could-not-be-opened-correctly/)

[**Google Chrome Profile Could Not Be Opened Correctly Error**](http://simplifyitco.com/google-chrome-profile-could-not-be-opened-correctly-error/)